# Migrate old admin's posts to his new user

Tags: database, nodes, users

I'm taking over maintenance of a Drupal site but the old admin is staying on as a user.

I need to adjust the ownership of the posts currently under uid 1.

Is this query sufficient or is uid associated with a blog post in other ways?

Is there an admin module for this process?

```
UPDATE `drupal_node_revisions` r,
`drupal_node` n
SET n.uid = 13392, r.uid = 13392
WHERE 
r.uid = 1
AND n.uid = 1
AND n.type = 'blog'
AND r.nid = n.nid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node data is stored in node table also.. It's a bad practice to change node content directly using sql queries...

You can use [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module to change node authors in bulk...

> This module augments Views by allowing bulk operations to be executed
>   on the displayed rows. It does so by showing a checkbox in front of
>   each node, and adding a select box containing operations that can be
>   applied. Drupal Core or Rules actions can be used.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I assumed like most platforms hand editing would not be best.  This site is on Drupal 6x so I will install https://drupal.org/node/161539/release?api_version%5B%5D=87 and see if I can resolve.  Much obliged!

Comment: I'm looking for the install directions.  Does this go in /modules or in /modules/views/modules?